# HAProxy define subdomain wildcard

Tags: subdomain, haproxy

I am trying to create a HAProxy script which matches certain subdomains to a specific backend.

Given the domains:

```
foo.x.y.z
bar.x.y.z
bar.a.b.c
baz.a.b.d.e
```

I want these frontends to be mapped to the backends foo, bar and baz.

I've tried to get the thing working by using hdr_beg() - but I'm missing something so it does not work :-/

This is my config so far:

```
frontend HttpFrontend
        bind *:80
        mode http
        acl fooBackend hdr_beg(host) -i foo.
        acl barBackend hdr_beg(host) -i bar.
        default_backend bazBackend

backend bazBackend
        mode http
        balance leastconn
        option forwardfor
        server node1 10.0.1.10:80 check inter 5000 rise 3 fall 3
        server node2 10.0.2.10:80 check inter 5000 rise 3 fall 3
        server node3 10.0.3.10:80 check inter 5000 rise 3 fall 3

backend fooBackend
        mode http
        option forwardfor
        server node4 10.0.1.14:80

backend barBackend
        mode http
        option forwardfor
        server node4 10.0.1.14:80
```

Can you give me a hint what I am missing?!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `use_backend`.

```
frontend HttpFrontend
    bind *:80
    mode http
    acl fooBackend hdr_beg(host) -i foo.
    acl barBackend hdr_beg(host) -i bar.

    use_backend fooBackend if fooBackend
    use_backend barBackend if barBackend

    default_backend bazBackend
<...>
```

Source: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#use_backend

Comment: I can't believe that I have overlooked that ... Thank you very much!